# Is it possible to do this integral?

Tags: integration

Is it possible to do this integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sech}^2(Bx)\operatorname{sech}^2(ax) dx,$$ where $B$ and $a$ are constants.

I tried using Mathematica, but no dice...

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't give a nice enough answer to your question. But hopefully can be extended to give a nice enough answer. Let us assume $a,b>0$. Let $$I(a,b) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sech}^2(ax) \text{sech}^2(bx)dx = 2 \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} \text{sech}^2(ax) \text{sech}^2(bx)dx}_{J(a,b)}.$$
We have
\begin{align}
\text{sech}^2(ax) \text{sech}^2(bx) & = \dfrac{16}{\left(\exp(ax) + \exp(-ax) \right)^2\left(\exp(bx) + \exp(-bx) \right)^2}\\
& = \dfrac{16 \exp(-2(a+b)x)}{(1+\exp(-2ax))^2(1+\exp(-2bx))^2}\\
& = 16 \exp(-(a+b)x) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (1+m)(1+k)(-1)^{m+k}\exp(-2(ak+bm)x)\\
& = 16 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (1+m)(1+k)(-1)^{m+k}\exp(-2(a(k+1)+b(m+1))x)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$I(a,b) = 16 \sum_{m,k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{m+k}(1+m)(1+k)}{a(k+1)+b(m+1)}$$

Comment: First numerator should be $16$ after we have

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was hoping, however, for there to be a nicer solution one could write down. An expression this complicated won't be very helpful in my calculation.